# Change the content inside the <td> with the help of id of <tr>

Tags: javascript, html

How can I get the second child node of a `tr`, which has 3 `td` in it?
I have a code

```
rows=document.getElementById('mytr');
rows.firstChild.innerHTML='ddsds';
rows.lastChild.innerHTML='dd';
```

Now I would like to change the content in the middile also. how can I do that?

```
rows.secondChild.innerHTML='ddsds';
```

will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access the childNodes or cells as array

rows.childNodes[1].innerHTML would do the second cell, as would

rows.cells[1].innerHTML

Answer (score 3):

Although I'd recommend using something like jQuery for this kind of manipulation, this is what you want:

```
var rows = document.getElementById('mytr');
var cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');

cells[0].innerHTML = 'ddsds';
cells[1].innerHTML = 'ddsds';
cells[2].innerHTML = 'dd';
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also use nextSibling,

```
rows.firstChild.nextSibling.innerHTML='ddsds';
```

and be careful while accessing child, these can return a text node if there are some white spaces. always try to validate if the child is not a text node using

`rows.firstChild.nodeType == 1` // this will check if the node is not a text node

Answer (score 1):

You can use .childNodes to find childnode by it's index.

```
rows.childNodes[1].innerHTML = 'foo'; // set foo to second child
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (rows.childNodes.length > 0)
    rows.childNodes[1].innerHTML = "ddsds";
```